# MATLAB implementation of Elevation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm trying to implement a piece of paper, but I got stuck in a part called elevation filter!
here is that part of this article:

[image: Elevation algorithm]

Does anyone know how to write it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the [Image Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/index.html) function [`watershed`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/watershed.html) to compute your *elevation*. I'll start with a simple example 300-by-300 matrix to represent your *height* data, shown in the first row of the figure below:

```
height = repmat(uint8([1:100 99:-1:50 51:1:150 149:-1:100]), 300, 1);
```

Each row has the same profile in this case. We can compute a *basin* matrix using `watershed`:

```
basin = watershed(height)+1;
```

This is shown in the second row of the figure below. Note that there are crests that are assigned a default value of 1 because they fall on the **edges** of the basins. You'll have to decide for yourself how you want to deal with these, as here I end up just lumping all the edges together into a pseudo-basin.

Next, we can use [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to compute a *minima* matrix (shown in the third row of the figure below) that maps the minimum value of each basin to all the points in that basin:

```
minValues = accumarray(basin(:), height(:), [], @min);
minima = minValues(basin);
```

And finally, the *elevation* can be computed like so (result shown in last row of figure below):

```
elevation = height - minima;
```

### Figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is strongly related to what in image processing is called [watershed transform](http://cmm.ensmp.fr/~beucher/wtshed.html) (or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_%28image_processing%29)).

According to watershed approach, a grayscale image is seen as a topographic relief and it is filled with water. Doing so, different regions of the image can be separated, according to the way different basins join once filled with water.

If watershed is your final aim, the image processing toolbox has an implementation for it. [Here](http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/images/ref/watershed.html).

---

In principle, in your problem, given a local minimum `q`, `height(p)`, for `p` close to `q`, solves the minimization problem

```
     height(p) = inf_{g} \int_g ||grad I (g) || dg
```

where `g` is curve which joins `p` and `q` and `I` is your image.

For more mathematical details, you can consider, for instance, [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.10.3852&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

For implementation details, matlab, for instance, should have mex code.

Comment: Thank you for your respond Acrobe, but my problem is not the Watershed Transform. This algorithm (Elevation) is used to denoise echocardiography images not for segmentation.